# Array of widths changes on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to have array `slide_widths` with widths of all `.slide` elements:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var $slider = $('.slider ul');
  var slider_width = $slider.width();
  var $slides = $('.slide');
  var slide_widths = $.map($slides, function(slide) {
    return slide.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  });

  console.log(slide_widths);
});
```

I get different results when I refresh my page:

```
1. [201.328125, 180, 214.28125, 180, 180, 180, 168.46875, 180, 145.078125, 144, 142.1875, 250.6875, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

2. [201.328125, 180, 214.28125, 180, 180, 180, 168.46875, 180, 145.078125, 144, 142.1875, 250.6875, 155.515625, 180, 180, 176.03125, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I guess this `map` function is still working when `console.log` outoputs an array? How can I avoid it ?

Comment: Could you try wrapping your code in a `setTimeout()` with a small delay of say 100ms? It may be that your DOM is not fully loaded when the JQuery initiates, and so for the elements that are not yet loaded, it's grabbing a width of 0.

Comment: $.map is synchronous so your console.log shouldn't be called first - could you put your code into a snippet/jsfiddle?

Comment: @TylerRoper when I run it with setTimeout() it works fine.

Comment: So does this solve your issue?

Comment: Is there any way to do this without setTimeout ?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that your function is grabbing the element widths before they're actually loaded, and so the not-yet-loaded elements are returning widths of 0.

Try using `$(window).on("load", function() {` instead of `$(document).ready(function() {`

`$(window).on("load"` will wait for all elements on the page to load, whereas `$(document).ready` will not.